# chart.js - how to draw and manage line when only one label present in chart js Linechart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart

I'm using Chart.JS v 2.9.3 to create a line chart

line-chart diagram to show the month-wise total of expenses of selected product

> For example, if the user select **XYZ** product then this charts would show the **monthly expenses** [Jan-2021-Dec-2021]
> and if that respective **product expense only present Jan-2021** then it displays month on y-Axes at staring

[image: reference image]

---

here is [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kkoUser/kbs203f4/32/)

---

1. Adding offset trick I had already tried  `xAxes : [{ offset:true }],`

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["jan-2021"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "month-year",
      data: [65],
      backgroundColor: "rgb(118, 101, 228)",
    }],
 },
  scales : {
      xAxes : [{
         offset:true
      }],
  },
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<div class="myChart">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
          </div>
```

[image: image of chart]

please refer to the above image for getting an idea of what I'm trying to archive, ***I'm not concern about dot*** that on the chart

As you can see, the points are stick to the y-axis. Is there a possibility to center the line chart when only one data is present in the diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart.js does not support this kind of use case since it gives a distorted image of your chart since point and label don't align anymore. If you really want this you can check beforehand in your code if there is only 1 data point there. If this is the case add an empty string in your labels array in the front and back and add zero at the front of back of your data array (or a slightly lower value as your single datapoint so that the scales don't get big steps) like so:

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["", "January-2021", ""],
    datasets: [{
      label: "month-year",
      data: [0, 134335066, 0],
      backgroundColor: "rgb(118, 101, 228)",
    }],
  },
  scales: {},
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<div class="myChart">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use align option:

```
var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  responsive: true,
  data: data,
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
      position: 'bottom',
      align: 'center'
    },


var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["", "January-2021", ""],
    datasets: [{
      label: "month-year",
      data: [0, 134335066, 0],
      backgroundColor: "rgb(118, 101, 228)",
    }],

  options: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
          position: 'bottom',
          align: 'center'
        },

  },
  scales: {},
};
```

refer to [this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think that is not a solution, what if we have another month list too as I already describe in question 
product expense available in Jan-2021 to dec-2021, please let me know if it is unclear to you :)